# Xcode cannot find cstddef

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, boost, std

Xcode (iOS) cannot for some reason find cstddef for a library I'm using (Boost). Does any one know how to fix this?

I am compiling under Mac OS X 10.8 with Xcode 4.6

Comment: if there's a framework, have you added it? have you imported or included into your app?

Comment: I have included the framework, is this correct ?

Comment: @JamesCampbell Can you tell us what your steps were?

Comment: Basically I created an Xcode project and used a version of boost specifically created as a Framework, here : which is where the error is being shown when I import it. I then used the code from here and a version of Libcurl : http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/asiohiper.html . When I compile just that in Xcode for iOS 6, I get a cstddef can't be found error in one of the boost header files of the framework. Even though I've told xcode to use the std library and it shouldn't happen. I can zip the project up if that would help ?

Comment: Fixed it, not compiling the .cpp file and including it in the file I wanted to use. Made it work, but I don't think thats a good thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make your project all Objective-C++, renaming all the files to *`.mm` extension.